# Cron occasionally fails with "grandchild #X failed with exit status 3"

Tags: linux, bash, cron, shell

I have cron jobs and every now and then they fail. Just after log message that the command has started, there is `grandchild #X failed with exit status 3` message.

On the next run scripts finishes correctly. It happens to different scripts with different run periods (from minutely to once-a-day scripts). There seems to be no pattern.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I ran scripts in crontab in `strace`. The problem is the script gets killed because of `SIGBUS`:

```
--- SIGBUS (Bus error) @ 0 (0) ---
exit_group(3)                           = ?
```

However, still don't know why this is happening.

Comment: You have to post some crontab entries.  This kind of error occurs when crond finds a syntax error in the command itself, like doing something fun with the date command.  crontab syntax is NOT the same as bash or ksh.  For example, the % character has to be escaped.

Comment: @jimmcnamara It cannot be wrong crontab syntax, because one minute the script ran, the very next it failed and the minute after it ran again. See my edit, the problem is SIGBUS.

Comment: This is likely not a problem with cron, grandchild if cron would be what you told cron to run. SIGBUS is the kernel/cpu/hardware telling your program it made a funky memory access. Can you tell us about what cron runs ? The full strace would be neat if you can post it (may contain sensitive info, so you may not want to post it).

Comment: One more time: please post at least one line of the crontab entry - one that has failed.

Comment: As mentioned by @jimmcnamara and others. **Please post the crontab entry/entries that are exhibiting the problem**.  If they point to a script, you might want to post that as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page for Signal (`man 7 signal`) a `SIGBUS` means `Bus error (bad memory access)`.
Since the problem is random or not easily reproduced 100% of the time, this means either;

1. The Cron job is calling a program or script that is randomly failing
2. A memory problem exists and should be checked for

If it is the former (#1), then check the program / script for any irregularities.
However, it *could* be a RAM problem, so you might want to get a Boot-disk with [MemTest86](http://www.memtest.org/) on it and run a check for an hour or so.